# Nested Exception could not execute statement: getting HTTP Status 500 in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I've been working on project in Spring, I'm trying to add functionality which will add int (mark in this case) to my MySQL database but after clicking button I've a following error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1364]; could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

This is the log from the console:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/eschool] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1364]; could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'value' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3003)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3503)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.addMark(Unknown Source)
```

The view - it suppose to change from disable to enable but it's not working too, don't know why exactly. I've got three students there but it shows 0.

Comment: The **relevant** code must be in the question itself. Not as links. But the error message is pretty clear. Have you read it?

Comment: Looks pretty straight forward to me. `Field 'value' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: Why code has to be in question? Now it's more legible
Yes I read it but still not quite sure what's wrong. I don't have permission to add values to tables or what?

Comment: @JMullen Optional value is in view.jsp and it's combobox

Comment: Code is required because your links will expire. When that happens, your question is worthless to other users trying to solve a similar issue. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: @PiotrSzczepanik the error, from MySQL, says "Field 'value' doesn't have a default value". So, that means you're trying to insert a row in some table, without telling what to store in the column "value", and there is no default value configured for this column, so MySQL doesn't know what to store in that column, hence the error.

Comment: Voting to close based on the official close reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**._

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection pool is exausted,then ensure that you are releasing connections and review transaction configuration.

Comment: Configuration is fine IMO

Comment: default value in database,jsp: DATE - YYYY-MM-DD or
DATETIME - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:S